# Sqoop import error with BigInt datatype

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop

While importing a table from SQLServer to Hive, I am facing the following exception

```
/tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/a6db7754847c4d49c9164758fcc079d7/ReceivedData.java:513:      error: incompatible types
this.IDReceivedData = Long.valueOf(__dataIn.readLong());
required: Long
found:    Double                                     
/tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/a6db7754847c4d49c9164758fcc079d7/ReceivedData.java:1007:    error:   incompatible types
  this.IDReceivedData = Long.valueOf(__cur_str);
                                    ^
required: Long
found:    Double
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/a6db7754847c4d49c9164758fcc079d7/ReceivedData.java uses  or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
```

Here is the command used to import the table

The datatype of the specific column(IDReceivedData) is BigInt in the database. what may be the problem here? Do i have to change the datatype of the column in the database? or any other changes with the sqoop import command.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<ip>:1433;database=temp;user=sa;password=pass" --table ReceivedData --hive-table temp.ReceivedData
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kalai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqoop does not support BigInteger currently, for a workaround you can map the specific column as string

```
--map-column-java IDReceivedData=String
```